# What are the pros and cons of having many tables vs many columns in a database and vice versa?

Tags: database, optimization

TLDR: 
What are the pros and cons of each of these database configurations in terms of performance, ease of management and any other considerations you might think of?

If there are only two types of 'loc'ations and only two types of entities, how would each of these three table configurations be better or worse than one another:

`Config 1`:

```
loc | allow | entity | entity_type | loc_type
2   | True  | jim    | user        | zone
29  | False | officer| class       | quadrant
```

`Config 2`:

```
zone | allow | entity | entity_type
2    | True  | jim    | user

&

quadrant | allow | entity | entity_type
29       | False | officer| class
```

`Config 3`:

```
zone | allow | user
2    | True  | jim

&

zone | allow | class

&

quadrant | allow | user

&

quadrant | allow | class
29       | False | officer
```

The first example combines all the data into one table (lets call it "permissions") and has extra columns defining the type of data in the loc and entity columns. The last example breaks it all up into 4 tables, which might be named "zone_user_permissions", "zone_class_permissions", "quadrant_user_permissions" and "quadrant_class_permissions".

The middle one is a bit of a compromise between the first and third.

Obvious differences are that the first single table configuration bears extra columns and thus stores more "extra" data than the last configuration. Where as the third one is spread out over multiple tables and might be more difficult to query in some circumstances.

So assuming there would be approximately an equal distribution of rows among all tables, what would the benefits and downsides be to each of these configurations?

Comment: Please just read up on [third normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form)

Comment: @EdHeal I actually don't know anything about database normalization, so I have a bit of reading to do...

Comment: ... Enjoy the rest of the day reading

Comment: @EdHeal Rest of the day? *looks at clock*. It's 12:10AM...

Comment: Lots of it to go.....Get a stiff coffee for a long night/day. BTW -  Koala bears finger prints cannot be distinguished from a humans. Interesting fact

Comment: @EdHeal I'm hypersensitive to coffee, so one coffee might last me the whole 24 hours. BTW - Dogs have three eyelids. Interesting fact.

Comment: And they fart and smile at you at the same time

Comment: @EdHeal So I've read up on 1NF, 2NF and 3NF, and it looks to me like both configuration 1 and 3 both meet the requirements of 3NF. Were you suggesting that one did not?

Comment: Have you heard of enumerated types and how much  better they are than strings?

Comment: @EdHeal Yes I have and I've considered them before but have not used them yet. I usually just use a number or a char to denote different types because I'm lazy. But lets assume that in this example the entity_type and loc_type columns are both enumerated types. Which configuration would be better? The first one because it condenses everything into one table and minimizes extra data usage because of enumerated types? Does the condensed version reduce flexibility for future database modifications? How do I chose one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109979/discussion-between-ed-heal-and-adjenks).